# Why am I getting a NullPointerException when fetching values from Futures?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, executorservice, callable

I'm using and `ExecutorService` to concurrently run some `Callables`. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
ArrayList<Book> objResults = new ArrayList<Book>();
ExecutorService esrExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
Set<Callable<ArrayList<Book>>> setCallables = new HashSet<Callable<ArrayList<Book>>>();

setCallables.add(new Callable<ArrayList<Book>>() {

    public ArrayList<Book> call() throws Exception {    
        ArrayList<Book> objAmazonResults = new ArrayList<Book>();

        try {    
            Amazon objAmazon = new Amazon();
            objAmazonResults = objAmazon.doSearch(strQuery);    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
        return objAmazonResults;    
    }

});


List<Future<ArrayList<Book>>> lstFutures;
try {
    lstFutures = esrExecutor.invokeAll(setCallables);

    for(Future<ArrayList<Book>> futFuture : lstFutures){
        if (futFuture.get().isEmpty() == false) //NullPointerException occurs here
            objResults.addAll(futFuture.get());
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

esrExecutor.shutdown();
```

I get a `NullPointerException` on this bit of code `if (futFuture.get().isEmpty() == false)`. I can't seem to figure out why or how this bit of code can possibly be null.

If you look at my `Callable` you'll see that I'm trapping all exceptions and simply printing the stacktrace and I always return `new ArrayList<Book>()`.

I'm not much for helping other debug my code soup on SO but sometimes everyone hits a roadblock but this kind of exceptions has taught me one thing — when chaining methods together, it's always harder to debug.

Comment: `objAmazonResults = objAmazon.doSearch(strQuery);` could be overwriting it with `null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be `objAmazon.doSearch(strQuery)` returns null?
Insert a check for this into the `Callable`.

The `Future` itself should never be null, and `Future.get()` will not return null, if the computation terminated with an exception (so catching all exceptions inside the `Callable` is not necessary).

Comment: Adding to what Phillip said, call() will be throwing null as it holds the code to what thread had to do. Add try catch and print stack trace inside call() method to find the place of exception.